# Not able to Intercept websocket client request using @Webfilter in quarkus

Tags: websocket, quarkus

I am migrating an application from thorntail to Quarkus , so I faced an issue of intercepting the websocket client request but same works fine in thorntail.

I am trying to intercept the websocket client request with @WebFilter but seems like it is not picking up the websocket client request , but it works fine with rest client .
Any Suggestion around this would be helpful.

Comment: Which quarkus websocket extensions are you using?

Comment: quarkus-undertow and quarkus-undertow-websockets